# fingerprint on asp.net

Tags: c#, java, actionscript-3, fingerprint

I am trying to do this goal, but I need some alternatives to got it.

I want to read a fingerprint using asp.net,silverlight, actionscript, i need get the finger and display the capture in the window.

I do it in C# with griaule biometrics SDK 2009, only can be possible using a java applet. I dont know if mix java + asp.net can be a good alternative. if yes, how can I to pass the value from asp.net to java applet?

I need some alternatives to do it.

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Silverlight?

If you have it working in a regular C# app, it might be possible to get it working in the browser via Silverlight. Then you can display it in that SL app or send it to the server via a web service.

Comment: I think on it, but silverlight is very limited when the goal is usb access, I need complete access to webcam, fingerprint and some COM Ports.